# Showing no audio output devices installed

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, asus-laptop

[image]

Asus in search in incredible A555L i installed audio drivers but not working . I tried allot but i cant find solution. i given to asus service center they are solved issue but its worked only one day again audio drivers is  gone.I struggled allot would you please anyone help me..i'll appreciate them

Device Manager
[image]

But if i restart my laptop sometimes its working audio drivers  and some times not working i don't understand what is the issue .. i'm getting mad with this.... audio drivers

[image]

I installed asus audio drivers ofter installed

I was clicked speakar button..then showing  Detecting problem then
[image]

I was clicked apply this fix then,[image]

then i clicked next button then,[image]

I restarted again...... not yet solved issue ..

Comment: In device manager sound driver is showing any warning ? can you post it here.

Comment: See my device manager

Comment: Where is sound device ? Might be hardware problem, check with service center.

Comment: i restarted again its working now

Comment: Check event viewer logs for applicable detail and check for a firmware BIOS update for the ASUS.

Comment: I dont no how to check firmware BIOS means..??i went once  service centre 4 days back its worked when i was there ..ofter restarting my lap again same issue

Comment: Same problem here. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. I'm also guessing that it's hardware issue.

Comment: Present woking fine to me i changed my inner laptop parts all except hardwire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give us some more information about your computer model, as I understand
that the A555L goes from A555LA to A555LF and may have several sub-models
depending on the CPU.

Your problem may be an intermittent hardware problem or software.
I will list below the software solutions I know, but if none works,
then most probably the problem is hardware.
Before starting, take backups and create a System Restore point.

1. **Replace old audio driver**
   When upgrading from a previous Windows version to Windows 10, the old driver
   may have been maintained. To reinstall, when Audio devices are showing in
   Device Manager, right-click on your audio device and choose Uninstall,
   then reboot.
2. **Install Asus drivers**
   If the Microsoft driver did not work for you, you might install the drivers
   from Asus. I have found drivers [here](https://www.asus.com/in/support/Download/3/669/0/11/YKn8uXguJ7PGeTEY/45/).
   Download and install at least the latest BIOS version using the flash utility
   under BIOS-Utilities, Realtek Audio Driver, and Chipset. Reboot.
3. **Windows Troubleshooter**
   From the Start button, type Troubleshoot, and then select Troubleshoot from the list of results. Select Playing Audio, then Run the troubleshooter.
   Reboot afterwards.

Below are some manipulations that helped some people but are somewhat doubtful.

4. **Modify the Speakers properties**
   Right-click on the sound icon at the bottom right corner in desktop and select Playback devices.
   In Playback tab, select your speakers, which is set as default, and click Properties. 
   Click Advanced tab. Under “Default Format”, alter the sample rate and bit depth until one of the settings works. Click Apply and OK to save the change.
5. **Disable Audio Enhancements**
   In the taskbar search box type Sound, and click on the Sound Control Panel option. In the new box that opens, right-click the default device, and select Properties. Click the Enhancements tab, and make sure to check the box labelled Disable all enhancements, and Apply.

Comment: ASUS IN SEARCH OF INCREADIBLE A555L i'll do same as above not yet solved issue

Comment: I did same as above your answer but not yet solved issue.....@harrymc

Comment: My guess then would be a hardware problem. Last software try: Boot in Safe mode and see if the problem happens.

Comment: Once upon a time issue will happen may i think hardware problem

Comment: I Changed my mother board from asus service centre its working

Answer (score 0):

i checkout and did all the google results but those not worked

my suggested solution is :

> update windows 10 (online update)

but i did these steps before:

- install usb sound card driver from windows and restart (source: this
  youtube video)  **then restart but not resolved**
- upgrade the audio device driver from device management in windows **then restart but not resolved**
- download my laptop drivers from website and install it **then restart but not resolved**
- install driverpack and install update all my hardwares driver  **then restart but not resolved**
- one another video in youtube caption is this occured for last update

then i decide to update and install the last new updates for windows 10

then restart

and its worked...

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by several different software or hardware issues in Windows. To diagnose, first check the **Device Manager**. You should have a few sound devices (speakers and microphones) listed under "Audio inputs and outputs" and audio chipsets under "Sound, video and game controllers".

- If you have no sound chipsets (e.g. Realtek Audio, Intel Audio, High Definition Audio Device), restart your computer and enter the BIOS menu before Windows starts (usually press F12 to get the boot menu), then check that internal audio devices have been enabled.
- If the devices are listed, but shows an error icon, you probably just need to update (or rollback) the drivers as discussed above.
- If you plug in a USB audio device, connect a bluetooth headset or connect to a TV via HDMI, does it add those devices on the device manager? Do they output audio? If yes, then you may have a hardware issue with your local/internal sound device. If no, its likely a software/driver/registry issue needed to be fixed.
- To diagnose this issue, select the audio chipsets listed, open its properties and look under general tab/device status as well as the events for errors and google those.

Here are the registry/software fixes to try:

1. If you have "Device was not migrated" in the events tab, check if the administrators group has "local service" and "network service" users as part of the group, using the "computer management" app. Or run a command prompt with admin rights, run the below commands and restart (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/kb5003173-killed-my-audio/03662044-80f9-45e0-ba20-a47d1e93488a) for more info):

---

```
net localgroup Administrators
net localgroup Administrators /add localservice
net localgroup Administrators /add networkservice
```

2. Search for "ease of access audio settings" in the start menu and then try to toggle "mono audio" on and off, and try to adjust the device volume there. (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/no-audio-output-device-is-installed-windows-10/111ed7db-9a9c-4c67-b094-393a5fd26f85?page=4))
3. Add this registry entry, as discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/no-audio-output-device-is-installed-windows-10/111ed7db-9a9c-4c67-b094-393a5fd26f85?page=4):

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations] 
"ConsoleSecurity"=hex:01,00,14,80,9c,00,00,00,a8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,\ 
  00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,01,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,\ 
  04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,00,\ 
  00,14,00,89,00,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,81,00,\ 
  00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,bf,03,0f,00,01,02,00,\ 
  00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,21,01,00,00,01,02,00,00,\ 
  00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,2b,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,\ 
  01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```