# Windows 10 Sound not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bios, sound-card

[image]

It starts with a red cross by the sound icon on task bar.

[image]

On checking playback devices I find all are grayed out and enabled. Regardless, it says no audio device plugged in. (Even though I have headphones plugged in.)

Things I've tried;
1) Running troubleshooter. (says audio peripheral is unplugged.)
2) Updating device drivers.
3) Uninstalling drivers and restarting pc.
4) Manually installing realtek audio drivers. It is enabled in startup applications but I am unable to open the realtek manager's control panel. Double clicking on RAVCpl64 does nothing.
5) Toggling onboard audio in BIOS settings (enable/disable)
6) Restarting windows audio and windows audio endpoint builder services in services. I also tried changing their log on to local system account and checking the box saying allow service to interact with desktop. I also tried changing registry and set `NoInteractiveServices` to 0

I have exhausted every solution I could find on net.

I dont know what to do now

Comment: When did this first occur? After a Windows update? Driver update? Was this a brand-new system with the issue?

Comment: i had assembled a desktop in march. sound was working fine then. recently i had issues and pc would hang and shut down unexpectedly. i had given motherboard in service center (they claim to have changed the registers) and replaced the hard disk followed by clean installation of windows 10.(updates were on. i didnt check before windows updated whether sound was working just after windows installation.) sound hasnt worked since then.

Answer (score 0):

Solution only for desktops with more than one sound line output :

Last update changes audio output jack  assignments.So no more green to green or black to black.Switch line positions to the speaker by trial.

Comment: mine resolved by update windows 10 details here: https://superuser.com/a/1537132/165591