# No audio in newer games on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, gaming, directx

I'm on the latest Windows 10 1803 17134.48, running on a ASUS ROG Maximus X Hero Intel Z370 motherboard with Realtek audio. Speakers are plugged into the headphone (green) jack in the back.

The hardware (and the Windows install) is 7 months old, and sound has worked great everywhere for most of that time.

Recently I do not get audio in most games. Audio still works fine in non-games (e.g. VLC, Chrome/Youtube etc) and in some games (older games?).

This makes me suspect that the problem is with Direct X / DirectSound, but since there is no way to install / reset that in Windows 10, it's hard to tell.

"Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)" is always set as the current audio device. When in e.g. VLC I can see the audio meter move in the volume mixer, but in games there's no output there.

Sound in games where Realtek is not working works fine when played thru a different sound device (a USB headphone amp with its own DAC).

I've searched for clues, here's a non-exhaustive list of things I've already tried:

- Deinstalled all other audio output devices that I am not using, such that there is no chance it can be switching to another. There was Nvidia audio or output to my monitor that is now gone, and there's only 1 audio device left (speakers).
- Checked DxDiag.exe to see if there were any errors. none.
- Checked Device Manager for any problems.
- Tried reinstalling Realtek drivers. Neither the February 2018 ones from the Asus site nor the absolute latest (June 5th 2018) make any difference.
- Tried unplugging any devices that are not keyboard/mouse/monitor/speakers.
- Tried re-installing Steam (some Steam games have audio, but wanted to try anyway).
- Disabled all sound effects in audio settings.
- Tried low bit rate (16 bit 44khz) and high (24 bit 48 khz) settings.
- Deselected allowing applications to take exclusive control.
- Spatial sound off.
- Quit as many concurrently running application, especially Skype.
- Run Windows Trouble-shooter.
- Checked per-app volume settings (all default).
- Checked in-game audio settings :) But yeah, no audio in games I am running for the first time.
- Checked Steam settings (nothing applicable).
- Checked Sonic Studio (sofware installed by the asus drivers) and made sure all settings are default / no effects).
- Installed older versions of Direct X.
- Disable Windows 10 fast start up.
- SFC /scannow
- Make sure I'm up to date on Windows update.
- Reboot a bunch of times.

None of this appeared to make any difference.

What I did not try yet:

- Reinstall Windows. Was hoping to avoid that, and seeing as how "fresh" this install is, I was hoping it is not necessary.

Comment: Go back to a restore point or backup prior to that update.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I appear to have only one restore point, and it is from very recent (after the problem started) :(

Comment: Try this for uninstalling updates: https://www.howtogeek.com/223864/how-to-uninstall-and-block-updates-and-drivers-on-Windows-10/

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths thanks again for the tip, but there are no driver updates of any kind in the Windows Update list. The only bigger update is Windows version 1803, but nothing specifically audio related.

Comment: While you might not have any driver updates in Windows update you might want to check the ASUS website for the most recent audio drivers. Also check your Windows audio settings to double check that the default device is set. After installing 1803 (while the device name was the same) some of my applications complained that the audio devices were gone and I had to reselect them. Also if you're using the Studio X tool make sure to check what's selected there, especially in case you redirected the audio for those games.

Comment: I haven't seen this one in your list : uninstall the Realtek device and reboot.

Comment: It doesn't have to be audio related in order to break audio. Preview version had a few iterations where audio broke due to a bug in the release. Roll back Windows until you have a known good point and then install an update, backup, rinse and repeat until you find the problem.

Comment: This isn’t a DirectX issue, DirectX is built-into Windows 10, it cannot be repaired/reinstalled

Comment: Seeing as the hardware is only 7 months old, it would be fair to assume your product is still under manufacturers guarantee. Have you tried contacting them to see if their conclusion is a fault with the hardware? Also, have you tried running games that aren't launching through steam? Manually installed games for example?

Comment: Seth: I did go to the asus website, I guess that's what I meant with reinstalling Realtek drivers above. I have triple-quadruple checked my settings.. remember, all apps and some games do audio just fine. There is only one audio device to choose from. I am not using Studio X.

Comment: @harrymc Just did that, and also selected "delete drivers" when uninstalling device. After reboot, it auto-added a Speakers device, but this time using "High Definition Audio Device", not "Realtek High Definition Audio" (presumably a generic windows driver?). Sadly, nothing changes: audio still plays great in most apps, not in most games.

Comment: @Ramhound yup, so I heard. Still, what is it that separates "most/newer games" from everything else that produces audio, other than the API? Maybe these games use wasapi? And just because something is installed with Windows doesn't mean it can't break.

Comment: @Aardappel If DX12 was broken then no DX games would work.  DX isn’t broken

Comment: @Myles: if it was a hardware problem, how come I get great error-free audio out of some apps? Sounds like a software problem to me. Replacing the mobo is a whole lot of work, so unless it is likely a hw problem, I'd rather not do that for no reason. But you're right, if nothing fixes it, this may be necessary.

Comment: @Ramhound things can be partially broken. For example, if sound related registry settings get corrupted, that likely doesn't influence rendering, or make anything stop working. A lot of software problems can be solved by reinstalling.. unless of course there is no reinstall option :(

Comment: So Reset Windows in that case.  I am telling you your problem is NOT because of a corrupt DirectX installation.  If you had a USB Headset you could confirm that’s the case. I just hate to see people spin up on a problem, and conclude it’s the one, it’s not. I obviously won’t be able to chnage your mind though.  So I can’t help you.

Comment: There are reports about conflicts with msi afterburner and some others advise to disable Windows 10 fast start up. You may also try the software from the [Latest Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/5993-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version.html), both the Realtek Audio Control app and the driver.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have msi afterburner nor any msi hardware. I did infact disable Windows 10 fast start up, forgot to put it in my list. Tried installing the latest from your link (which is very recent, so who knows it is better than the drivers I had!) but installing it from the device manager says "best drivers already installed", and trying from the commandline with dism.exe (with unpacked .cab) says "no packages were found that require processing"

Comment: @harrymc: the drivers on https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-X-HERO-WI-FI-AC/HelpDesk_Download/ are much older and pre-date Windows 1803, I guess Asus is slow to update? And drivers from Realtek.com are even older.

Comment: @harrymc ok, after installing the older drivers from february from Asus, the june 5th version from your link is now installing. Rebooted, verified Realtek drivers are now at June 5th. Sadly, still no change in the audio situation.

Comment: You have done everything possible and imaginable in vain. Sadly, the only idea left to me is that Windows 1803 seems to be incompatible with your hardware. If the update to 1803 happened less than 28 days ago, you might be able to roll it back and block it out until the next Windows major update which might fix the problem. Let me know if you want me to give an answer regarding this process. Get also in touch with Asus Support, as they might know a workaround for the problem (but do not let the 28 days elapse).

Comment: @harrymc Not only have the 28 days passed, when I looked earlier there were no restore points from before the problem. So complete re-install is my only option. If a major audio chip like Realtek is not compatible with Windows 1803, I'd expect a LOT of people to have the same problem, and I did not see that many posts in all my googling of people that had the exact same problem. I'd also expect either Realtek or MS to address it at some point. I'll get in touch with Asus support. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: If you get no joy from Asus Support, and if you wish to downgrade back to Windows 10 1709, let me know and I will detail the necessary procedure in an answer.

Comment: @Aardappel can you give some examples of games where the audio works and games where the audio doesn't work?

Comment: @harrymc I don't think downgrading to an older Windows is a good solution.. I don't want to forever be stuck at an old version. Seems so far the only solutions are reinstalling Windows (which maybe fixes it), or play audio for games thru another device.

Comment: @marijnr Sound does not work: Supreme Commander Forged Alliance, Bioshock 2, Subnautica, Deus Ex Human Revolution, GRID, GTA IV, Project CARS.
Sound works: Supreme Commander 1, many indie games (e.g. Mindustry), old games (Doom & Quake). And of course music players and web browsers.

Comment: For everyone that is still following along, I just got a USB headphone amp (has its own DAC, so presumably does not go thru Realtek), and sound in games is working. This is an ok workaround, still would love to solve this problem without reinstalling Windows though.

Comment: The recent windows update (1803, as you mentioned) included some changes to how windows handles audio. Windows now has the ability to redirect audio built in. It doesn't work very well... but it's there. If I had to guess, Sonic Studio III may be conflicting just by being installed. If possible, uninstall just that, then restart. Another note: old games use DirectSound. DirectSound was removed from Windows in Vista. Newer games (and all other modern apps) use WASAPI. I believe DX10+ somehow redirects DirectSound output from older games to WASAPI.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong deinstalled Sonic Studio III (and other Asus non-essential software like Sonic Radar), rebooted and.. omg, sound in games thru Realtek works again! So "Sonic Studio III interferes with sound in Windows 1803" is the official answer to this question. Can you put that in an answer so I can give you your well-deserved bounty points?
And btw.. WTF Asus? This cost me way too many hours to fix. A good reminder to never install all the extra crap device makers want you to install.

Comment: If you google "windows 1803 sonic studio 3" not a lot comes up. Some people have apparently had "crackling and popping" problems with this combination, but I don't see any posts about losing sound in games (that use WASAPI apparently) entirely. I wonder why I am one of few people who had this problem? Oh well, hopefully this page will help others that run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict between Sonic Studio III (packaged with some ASUS products) and Windows 10 version 1803. This is likely because Sonic Studio III includes features for redirecting audio from applications to different physical audio outputs and Windows 10 version 1803, which was released recently via windows updates, provides similar functionality. Even without redirection enabled in either, there is still a potential for conflict just by having them installed together.

Remove Sonic Studio III completely by going to <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > [image: Windows Settings Icon] Settings > `Apps` and uninstall Sonic Studio III. Then restart Windows. You may have to remove the entire ASUS Sonic Suite (but not the ASUS/Realtek drivers).

Comment: I suddenly lost my sound for some games on steam today. Youtube, music everything works fine but some games. Your answer saved me.

Comment: mine resolved by update windows 10 details here: https://superuser.com/a/1537132/165591

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and the 'fix' as such was a bit bizarre and quite simple.

In my case, two people use the same computer, and the sound in just games (system sounds still worked fine) was disabled for the second user. To reproduce the issue, all I have to do is the following:

- log on as person A
- switch user to person B (person A is still logged in)
- person B will not have sound in games

Logging off person A and only having person B logged in meant that games started playing sound once more without any other action.

I couldn't find any settings in Windows that meant only the first logged in user could have sound in games.

For reference, I tried updating drivers, uninstalling sound related software, reinstalling multiple types of software, using any combination of administrator vs normal user accounts, etc, etc based on all the various answers I found via various search engines to no avail before I figured out the above.

Hopefully the two account issue (and logging off one of the accounts) solves this for others.